# sympy symbolic integration sometimes returns integral sometimes return error

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math, integral

I am trying to calculate the following [integral](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KdmMl.png) and I get either an error or a symbolic [answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQRsO.png) , SympPy isn't actually calculating the integral

```
from sympy import sin, cos, integrate, pi, symbols
t = symbols('t')
u =(-0.029788*sin(t)+0.00078986*cos(2*t)+0.9997)/(-0.019861*sin(t)+0.00039482*cos(2*t)+0.99961)
Q = integrate(u,(t,pi,2*pi))
display(Q)
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60493032/sympy-integral-not-being-evaluated?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want numerical answer (as you can expect when using definite limits that are numeric) then you can skip the attempt to get a symbolic solution -- there may not be one per reference link in comment -- and just create an `Integral` object and ask for a numerical approximation:

```py
...
>>> from sympy import Integral
>>> Integral(u,(t,pi,2*pi)).n(3)
3.16
```

Comment: Thank you, that was only an example, what if I want a symbolic answer?

Comment: see the answer given in the first comment that suggested this is a duplicate question

Comment: It's important to understand that the vast majority of integrals cannot be computed symbolically at all.